# Copying zip (and some compressed files) over smb takes a lot of time (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: samba

When I copy paste a compressed file, its stuck as shown in the image. After sometime, the file get copied at full speed. This issue only happens with compressed files and not others. If I copy a folder with multiple zip, then the same thing happens with each zip file.

I noticed the drive activity as soon as I start copy, the drive is not getting used.

[image]

Comment: It's Windows side? Antivirus?

Comment: Antivirus disabled too (Tested now)